# Centering content issue

Tags: css, center, alignment

Can anyone tell me what I need to do in order to get the following page to center the contents correctly?

I've been trying to work with something else I used earlier in the day from here:

```
#divWrapper {margin:0 auto; text-align:center;} 
#div {text-align:left;}
```

But this isn't working for me.  One of the pages I need help with is here:
REDACTED

Thank you for any help, I'm just trying to get this fixed before I can head off to bed :\

Comment: You need to add width to the `#divWrapper`. Without width 'margin:0 auto;' won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#main-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    border-top: 3px solid #DADADA;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    overflow:auto;
    zoom:1;
}
```

try this one. replace the existing with this. it should center the content.

Comment: PERFECT! THANK YOU AND GOOD NIGHT! ;)

Comment: things to note when centering: 1.) if you center a container using the `margin:x auto x` method, the container needs to have a non-percentage width 2.) parent width not necessary but it should be bigger to admire the power of the centering 3.) container must be a block-level element 4.) no floats necessary. the `zoom` and `overflow` were just added to adjust the baseline of your container since it contains floating items.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips.  I'm just now starting to heavily use css so I'm still stumbling my way through from time to time ;)

Comment: This does not answer your question! Google css media queries if you wish to work with different screen sizes, or use javascript to calculate the width

Answer (score 2):

It needs a width! to work correctly.

Comment: .newcontent has a width of 100%

Comment: to use a width of 100%, you need to apply a margin all round, its impossible to calculate without a true width.  a margin of 10% will apply a margin of 100px all around

Comment: Philip, thank you for the responses, can you tell me how I need to manipulate the actual live code I'm using? I'm using Chromes Developer tools to try different things and nothing is helping.

Comment: you just change the margin value to 10%:ie margin:10%;  You can use javascript to calculate the width of the screen or use media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Give your #divWrapper a width. By default the width will expand as far as the containing element, so to create the appearance of it being centered, its width needs to be less than its containing element.

Answer (score 1):

You can only center elements with `margin:0 auto` when you provide a fixed width from which the margins can position themselves from automatically. So add a fixed with to your wrapper and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You might also need to specify text-align:center; if you want the actual div contents centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `#divWrapper {margin:0 auto; text-align:center;width:960px}`

```
#div {text-align:left;width:500px}
```

Edit:[image]
There are typing mistakes in your CSS.
Check this updated CSS for margin-inner & margin-inner-right. It will fix your problem

```
#main-inner {
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        border-top:3px solid #dadada;
        margin-top:20px;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
}


#main-inner-right {

        position:relative;
        width:640px;
        text-align:left;
        margin-top:20px;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm not actually using divWrapper and #div on my page, I'm trying to tweak what is already there.  Would it be possibly for you to look at the live code and tell me what I need tweaked?  Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Scott - That page uses a fixed width of 960px for the content wrappers.  The illusion of vairable width is given by repeating background images in the top-level wrapper elements which arwe 100% width, and auto margin.

Comment: Check my updated reply. Please mark as answer if it helped you. Damien